# Which file holds the path settings? What are the difference between Windows and Ubuntu path setting?

Tags: 11.10

How can I change them by directly editing the file ? echo $PATH returns this : /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: It might be a duplicate question. If it is, then please flag it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Global path settings: /etc/environment

User specific settings: ~/.bashrc

The paths are normally updated by the system when you install packages or change configurations e.g. proxy settings. Anyway, you can also change the paths or other environment variables editing the above files directly.

Comment: Julio: I dont have any file or folder in my system as you mentioned above.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables   for more details.